# Reference images from within a zip/tar file from html/javascript via library, possible?

Tags: javascript, html

This may seem like a duplicate of a similarly worded question. However, a major difference will hopefully be made apparent.

Not looking for space efficiency, but request efficiency. Lazy loading may satisfy this. However, for cases where contents need to be simultaneously shown for user experience as quickly as possible, lazy loading doesn't help.

**Is it possible for the html server to serve a zip or tar file where the components are directly accessible?** Library would behind the scenes do the following..

1. Download the tar file on first access.
2. Extract it and populate the cache.
3. Return the cached element when called.
4. Bonus points if the tar ball can be downloaded incrementally or behind the scenes with a background thread when the browser is idle but eagerly when the code requests its.

Use case: Tar ball of 100 thumbnails which will be displayed as gallery on screen.
Possible syntax may be:

```
<img data-src="https://example.com/imgs.tar/img001.jpg" class="tarload" />

<script>
   const obj = TarLoad()
   obj.observe()
</script>
```

Comment: I think the premise of efficiency is probably flawed, but maybe take a look at this. https://github.com/InvokIT/js-untar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this is absolutely NOT more efficient than making multiple requests for images. Browsers can actually parallelize the requests to a large extent (I think 6 HTTP requests at a time in Chrome and 31 in Firefox? Not entirely sure). Therefore, the overhead of downloading dozens of images is very similar to the overhead of a single TAR. The difference is that when parallelized, the images can be rendered immediately after each request finishes (so smaller images render first), whereas with an archive of images, each image can at best be rendered serially (by streaming the archive) and at worst will need to wait for ALL the images to load before displaying any. Plus, the runtime cost of extracting a TAR or ZIP isn't worth it, not to mention the extra JavaScript you need to download to even support something like this.

**With all that being said**, what you're suggesting is definitely possible. You can do this with either a ZIP or a TAR. I don't know of any good **streaming** untar libraries, but I authored a very efficient and tiny streaming unzip library [`fflate`](https://github.com/101arrowz/fflate). First add the library from a CDN:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fflate/umd/index.js"></script>
```

Add your images:

```html
<img data-src="https://example.com/imgs.zip/img001.jpg" class="zipload" />
<img data-src="https://example.com/imgs.zip/img002.jpg" class="zipload" />
<img data-src="https://example.com/others.zip/img001.jpg" class="zipload" />
```

Then run this JavaScript:

```js
const zipFiles = {};
for (const img of document.querySelectorAll('img.zipload')) {
  const fullSrc = img.getAttribute('data-src');
  // Finds the filepath of what to extract
  const fnInd = fullSrc.indexOf('.zip/') + 4;
  if (fnInd == 3) throw new Error(`Invalid data-src "${fullSrc}"`);

  const zipURL = fullSrc.slice(0, fnInd);
  const filepath = fullSrc.slice(fnInd + 1);
  if (!zipFiles[zipURL]) zipFiles[zipURL] = {};
  // Stores ZIP URLs, filepaths, and elements together
  zipFiles[zipURL][filepath] = img;
}
for (const zipURL in zipFiles) {
  const filepaths = zipFiles[zipURL];
  // Download the ZIP
  fetch(zipURL).then(async res => {
    // unzip logic
    const unzipper = new fflate.Unzip(async file => {
      // If this is one of the images we want...
      if (file.name in filepaths) {
        // Read the image into a data stream
        const imgStream = new ReadableStream({
          start(controller) {
            file.ondata = (err, chunk, final) => {
              if (err) controller.error(err);
              else {
                controller.enqueue(chunk);
                if (final) controller.close();
              }
            }
            file.start();
          },
          cancel() {
            file.terminate();
          }
        });
        // Create a blob from the stream
        const blob = await (new Response(imgStream)).blob();
        // Use a blob URL as the source
        filepaths[file.name].src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      }
    });
    // Asynchronous parallelized extraction
    unzipper.register(fflate.AsyncUnzipInflate);
    // Manually push each chunk in the ZIP stream through fflate
    const reader = res.body.getReader();
    while (true) {
      const { done, value } = await reader.read();
      if (done) {
        // last chunk is empty
        unzipper.push(new Uint8Array(0), true);
        break;
      };
      unzipper.push(value);
    }
  });
}
```

I tested this code and it works quite nicely (still slower and more memory intensive than without any ZIP, but it IS pretty cool to be able to do this all in JavaScript.)

Comment: Thank you.  I knew about the 6 in flight parallels messages chrome supports which is what im developing on (Did not know Firefox did so many). The page will have as many thumbnails on the page as possible up to 70 max. They are very small 5K jpegs.

Comment: Testing this answer tomorrow.